# Time Picker in UIAlertView

Tags: swift3, uialertview

I'm in need of a popup that asks for a time input, I figured an alertview would be the way to go but I have no idea where to begin embedding a time picker into an alertview.

Unless there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can add `datePicker` in `AlertController`, try like this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/40191156/6433023

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift UIAlertController with pickerView button action stay up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190629/swift-uialertcontroller-with-pickerview-button-action-stay-up)

Comment: @NiravD i think its not a duplicate since the question is different. however the answer is the same. but if people are searching for answer this is the thread that they will found. but the thread you mention are questioning something else. and it should be more explain on why it would help the pickerview to be on top instead of bottom.

but this question is simply on how to implement a TimePickerView on an uialertview.

Answer (score 5):

For anybody else, I adapted the question in the comments to be a time picker like so:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
let pickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
let editRadiusAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose ETA", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
editRadiusAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set ETA", style: .default, handler: nil))
editRadiusAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
self.present(editRadiusAlert, animated: true)
```

Comment: It throws many errors with constraints "A constraint factory method was passed a nil layout anchor.  This is not allowed, and may cause confusing exceptions. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintToNilAnchor(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future. ... [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

Answer (score 1):

You can use this component for the alert feel with both date and time picker

https://github.com/palKaran/UIAlertDateTimePicker

Comment: For only time picker, this library doesn't work. It is good for both date and time picker. Is there any other library for Time picker only?