# swift ios adding date picker to an alert in swift to be saved to local db using core data

Tags: ios, swift

i am using alert with a textfield input to save the data, what i want to know is i wanted to add a date picker to the alert so that the user will add name and then date. i have already made it possible saving the name but i am having trouble on adding date picker code and how would it be added to an alert. the code is below.

code of the alert:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Chore", message: "", preferredStyle:
        UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //this is the field where the user add the name
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: textFieldHandler)

    let a =  loggedInUsername
    if ((a?.lowercased().range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
        print("true")
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

            let newItem : String = (alert.textFields?.first?.text)!
            if !newItem.isEmpty {

                let item = Item(name: newItem)
//                        let item2 = Item(name: newItem2)
                self.saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem: item!)

                self.setUpCollectionView()

            }
        }))
```

code for saving to local db using core data:

```
func saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem : Item) {
    let context = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "GroceryItem", in: context)

    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    //set the entity values
    item.setValue(groceryItem.name, forKey: "name")
    item.setValue(false, forKey: "isSelected")
    item.setValue(loggedInUserHouseNumber, forKey: "houseNo")

    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("ang item:", groceryItem.name)
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: The question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514206/3580356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello You can use this code:

**Step:-1** Take Variable at Top:

```
var datePicker:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
```

**Step:-2** Create alert with textfield:

```
    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        self.doDatePicker()
        textField.inputView = self.datePicker
        textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolBar
    }

    // 3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
        if textField?.text != ""{
            print("Text field: \(textField?.text!)")
        }
    }))

    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Step:-3** Call this functions

```
func doDatePicker(){
    // DatePicker
  // datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 220, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    // ToolBar

    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adding Button ToolBar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeNewVC.doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeNewVC.cancelClick))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.toolBar.isHidden = false

}


@objc func doneClick() {
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter1.timeStyle = .none

    datePicker.isHidden = true
    self.toolBar.isHidden = true
}

@objc func cancelClick() {
    datePicker.isHidden = true
    self.toolBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Although Thing is ok to work, but in real time we should avoid using datepicker in alertview.

**Note:-** Instead of it make a pop-up window or else use .xib file and inside it take 2 textfields and then use one as name and second as date-picker.

Or else You can also use this Third party support which somewhat matches your requirement :- [Alert Modifications](https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers)

Comment: does the data that been saved belong to certain Sir , like if i add name Abhira with the date which is today , the data is abhira with the data equalt to today

Comment: yes like i have explained you the code to save data in core data. You can use the same logic by adding another textfield. First for name. Second For Date. And then pass both the data to the function and it will save

Comment: @DurnKurvirck If this also helped you approve my answer here also. I will be making a proper code for you.

Comment: can i send you my practice project file Sir ?

Comment: can you integrate that to my code above? i mean the full one where in i can add name , date , address

Comment: yes you can. I will cross verify that and mail you back

Comment: ok wait i am formatting good code for you with implementation.

Comment: Ill wait sIR for that

Comment: @DurnKurvirck Wait for that for 1-1.5 hr. I am stuck in some work will get back to you for sure

Comment: thats longs i see ,

Comment: i will wait sir

Comment: btw that question is connected to the question you have helped me o

Comment: @DurnKurvirck Look into the Question i have edited. Do refer the notes i have posted.

Comment: Thank You. i will try it

Comment: May i ask you another question , sorry if im too curious

Comment: please come in chat. As StackOverflow doesnt allow us to solve the queries in comment

Comment: my reputation is low for chat , can you please create

Comment: @DurnKurvirck The chat is already created, Refer the comment section of the other answer on which we are discussion. that core data save function. From that you can come to chat , i am already in

Answer (score 13):

**Adding Date Picker to an alert in Swift 5**

```
    let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    myDatePicker.timeZone = .local
    myDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    myDatePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 270, height: 200)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.view.addSubview(myDatePicker)
    let selectAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        print("Selected Date: \(myDatePicker.date)")
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(selectAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Quick and easy option :D

Comment: Looks bad on iOS 14.

Comment: Add myDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels for iOS 14 to see the wheels format

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'blank new lines' trick you can achieve this in Swift 5 by doing:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 270, height: 200)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TITLE", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.view.addSubview(datePicker)

let selectAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    print("Selected Date: \(datePicker.date)")
})
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(selectAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alert, animated: true)
```

It looks good but keep in mind it's hacky and can break in the future