# Swift 5: How to add text and date when pressing a button?

Tags: swift, datepicker

I'm trying to make it so when I press a button, I can add the cell's text and a date. For the date part, I tried looking at different Pods or Swift Manager Packages but couldn't find anything.
Here's is the code so far for the addButtonPressed. I'd like to add code so I can add the date as well:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            let newProduct = Product(context: self.context)
            newProduct.name = textField.text
            
            self.products.append(newProduct)
            self.saveProducts()
        }
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new category"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[And here is the simulator with what I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JfdX.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: just add another textfield using a date picker as its inputView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621092-inputview

Comment: I think this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547677/swift-ios-adding-date-picker-to-an-alert-in-swift-to-be-saved-to-local-db-using/49550613

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Getting a date from the user? Adding an item to your table view's model that contains a category name and a date? Displaying an entry in your table view that shows both the category name and a formatted date string?

Comment: @Setar, that actually helped! Thanks!